# Broadcast specific element of vector to another vector

Tags: c++, sse, simd, avx

How can I extract a single float from an index in a __m256 vector, and broadcast it to a result vector?

Pseudocode:

```
__m256 input = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
__m256 output = __mm256_selectidx(input, 2);

// output [0 .. 7] now consists of input[2], that is, {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}
```

Relevant functions seems to be extract/insert or permute, but the documentation is scarce / I don't really understand it. Broadcast family also looks good, but only works on memory operands?

Comment: Is the element index (2 in your example above) a compile-time literal constant, or does it need to be a run-time value (i.e. a variable) ?

Comment: It's an immediate value / constant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For AVX-only (i.e. no AVX2) you can do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

#define _mm256_selectidx(v, i) ({\
     __m256 vt = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(v, v, (i >> 2) | ((i >> 2) << 4)); \
     vt = _mm256_permute_ps(vt, _MM_SHUFFLE(i & 3, i & 3, i & 3, i & 3)); \
})

int main(void)
{
    __m256 v0 = _mm256_setr_ps(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
    __m256 v1 = _mm256_selectidx(v0, 2);
    float f0[8], f1[8];

    _mm256_storeu_ps(f0, v0);
    _mm256_storeu_ps(f1, v1);

    printf("v0: %g %g %g %g %g %g %g %g\n", f0[0], f0[1], f0[2], f0[3], f0[4], f0[5], f0[6], f0[7]);
    printf("v1: %g %g %g %g %g %g %g %g\n", f1[0], f1[1], f1[2], f1[3], f1[4], f1[5], f1[6], f1[7]);

    return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
$ gcc -Wall -mavx test_avx_select.c && ./a.out
v0: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
v1: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

Note that this code uses a gcc extension for macros which can behave like functions - if you're using a compiler which doesn't support this extension then you will probably need to use an inline function and hope that the compiler can deal with the compile-time constants required by the AVX intrinsics.

Comment: Clever solution (+1). I wonder how the AVX2 version performs compared to the AVX only version.

Comment: Thanks - the AVX version is probably more efficient, but it's limited to compile-time constants for the element index, whereas the AVX2 version will work with a run-time element index.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted, thanks. Can this solution (with some modification) be used for SSE2 aswell?

Comment: Sure - it's much easier for SSE though - you just need `_mm_shuffle_ps` - I'll post another answer with an SSE version.

Comment: With a compile-time constant `i`, you could `_mm256_shuffle_ps` to broadcast within a 128-bit lane, then `vinsertf128` to duplicate the low half, or `vperm2f128` to duplicate the high half.

Answer (score 3):

If you have AVX2 then could use `_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps`:

```
#define _mm256_selectidx(v, i) _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(v, _mm256_set1_epi32(i))
```

Obviously this will generate several instructions, depending on how your compiler handles `_mm256_set1_epi32` and whether the element index is a compile-time constant or not.

Demo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

#define _mm256_selectidx(v, i) _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(v, _mm256_set1_epi32(i))

int main(void)
{
    __m256 v0 = _mm256_setr_ps(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
    __m256 v1 = _mm256_selectidx(v0, 2);
    float f0[8], f1[8];

    _mm256_storeu_ps(f0, v0);
    _mm256_storeu_ps(f1, v1);

    printf("v0: %g %g %g %g %g %g %g %g\n", f0[0], f0[1], f0[2], f0[3], f0[4], f0[5], f0[6], f0[7]);
    printf("v1: %g %g %g %g %g %g %g %g\n", f1[0], f1[1], f1[2], f1[3], f1[4], f1[5], f1[6], f1[7]);

    return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
$ gcc -Wall -mavx2 test_avx2_select.c && ./a.out
v0: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
v1: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm stuck with only AVX... Solutions for SSE2 only would also be welcome

Comment: OK - I've added a separate AVX-only answer now which works with a compile-time constant for the element index.

Answer (score 1):

For SSE it's much simpler - you can just use `_mm_shuffle_ps`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <xmmintrin.h>

#define _mm_selectidx(v, i) _mm_shuffle_ps(v, v, _MM_SHUFFLE(i, i, i, i))

int main(void)
{
    __m128 v0 = _mm_setr_ps(2, 3, 4, 5);
    __m128 v1 = _mm_selectidx(v0, 2);
    float f0[4], f1[4];

    _mm_storeu_ps(f0, v0);
    _mm_storeu_ps(f1, v1);

    printf("v0: %g %g %g %g\n", f0[0], f0[1], f0[2], f0[3]);
    printf("v1: %g %g %g %g\n", f1[0], f1[1], f1[2], f1[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
$ gcc -Wall -msse test_sse_select.c && ./a.out
v0: 2 3 4 5
v1: 4 4 4 4
```